# Python that executes Fabric doesn't work (error) on Linux

Tags: python, linux, fabric

I came to you for some helps, I have one Python script that collects my machines IP of my network (192.168.1.X to 192.168.1.Y).

For information, i'm working on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and Python version is 2.7

So, this is my **Python script** execution (with collected IP as string for ip_list) :

```
import subprocess

ip_list = "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5"

cmd2 = ("fab -f /home/user/fabfile.py -H " + ip_list + " -u user -p password auto_install")

proc2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

My **Fabric script** is just a script in bash that I put in the machines and I execute it, here is a sample :

```
put("/home/user/bash_script","/home/user/bash_script",False)

sudo('bash /home/user/bash_script')
```

BUT ... this error appears in terminal when i do sudo python mypythonscript.py :

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
/bin/sh: 2: -u: not found
```

Comment: You didn't show the value of `ip_list`. You should [edit] your question and create a [mre]. The error message `/bin/sh: 2: -u: not found` probably means that there is a newline before `-u` which makes the shell interpret `-u` as a command.

Comment: The value of ip_list is a string which contain : 192.168.4.1,192.168.4.2,192.168.4.3,192.168.4.4 ... I'll edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, you saved me ! @Bodo

I didn't make a print of my cmd2 but it appears that there is a **\n** between **ip_list** and **-u**

So i did cmd2=cmd2.replace("\n","") and now i have another problem that i will check out.

Thank you :)

Comment: The code shown in the question would not produce a value of `cmd2` that contains `'\n'`.

Comment: Hello, so it seems that my previous code which is getting my ip adress list does add a \n automatically.

Here is a sample : cmd1 = ("python denios/denioso/fritom.py -updateClient | grep -oP '(?<=-H ).+?(?= -u)'")

Comment: Yes, this must be the cause. And this shows why it is important to copy&paste code to the question that actually reproduces the problem instead of showing some untested modified code.